# dovecot sharing folder with sql based authentication

Tags: dovecot

I want to share an imap folder.
Typically this can be done by ACL and the corresponding config files.

However... i have an sql based authentication of users in dovecot.

So, what would be the easiest way to implement and maintain this?

```
#user_query = \
user_query = SELECT CONCAT(homedir, maildir) AS home, CONCAT('maildir:', homedir, maildir) AS mail, uid, gid, CONCAT('*:storage=', quota, 'M') as quota_rule FROM mail_users WHERE (username = '%u' OR email = '%u')

#password_query = \
password_query = SELECT username AS user, password_enc AS password, CONCAT(homedir, maildir) AS userdb_home, uid AS userdb_uid, gid AS userdb_gid,  CONCAT('maildir:', homedir, maildir) AS userdb_mail, CONCAT('*:storage=', quota, 'M') as userdb_quota_rule FROM mail_users WHERE (username = '%u' OR email = '%u') AND ((imap = 1 AND '%Ls' = 'imap') OR (pop3 = 1 AND '%Ls' = 'pop3') OR ((postfix = 'Y' AND '%Ls' = 'smtp') OR (postfix = 'Y' AND '%Ls' = 'sieve')))

## Mailbox locations and namespaces
mail_location = mbox:~/mail:INBOX=/var/mail/%u
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
}


service auth {
  unix_listener auth-userdb {
    #mode = 0666
    #user = 
    #group = 
  }

  # Postfix smtp-auth
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    mode = 0660
    user = postfix
    group = postfix
  }

  # Exim4 smtp-auth
  unix_listener auth-client {
    mode = 0660
    user = mail
    #group = Debian-exim
  }

  # Auth process is run as this user.
  #user = $default_internal_user
}

service dict {
  # If dict proxy is used, mail processes should have access to its socket.
  # For example: mode=0660, group=vmail and global mail_access_groups=vmail
  unix_listener dict {
    #mode = 0600
    #user = 
    #group = 
  }
}

service stats {
  unix_listener stats-reader {
    group = vmail
    mode = 0666
  }
  unix_listener stats-writer {
    group = vmail
    mode = 0666
  }
}
```

Stripped all the unneccessary comments and values of the config above for better reading.
Maildirs all have the same uid/gid, so this will be not an issue.

As far as i understood, first i have to enable ACL, creating a new namespace, and then define the "database" where the sharing permissions/folders are stored, right?

ACL:

```
##
## Mailbox access control lists.
##

# vfile backend reads ACLs from "dovecot-acl" file from mail directory.
# You can also optionally give a global ACL directory path where ACLs are
# applied to all users' mailboxes. The global ACL directory contains
# one file for each mailbox, eg. INBOX or sub.mailbox. cache_secs parameter
# specifies how many seconds to wait between stat()ing dovecot-acl file
# to see if it changed.
plugin {
  acl = vfile:/etc/dovecot/global-acls:cache_secs=300
}

# To let users LIST mailboxes shared by other users, Dovecot needs a
# shared mailbox dictionary. For example:
plugin {
  acl_shared_dict = file:/etc/dovecot/shared-mailboxes
}
```

(from documentation https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/shared_mailboxes/shared_mailboxes/ )

Did not work as expected, dovecot segfaults.